# Integrate Odoo 15 with Django

Tags: django, odoo

I'm trying to build a Django REST API Project by retrieving data from Odoo, for that I need first of all to connect to odoo database. Any idea of how to do that !?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Odoo External API using XML-RPC and you can find more details in below Odoo documentation links:

[Odoo External API](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/api/external_api.html?highlight=xml%20rpc#external-api)

[Web Services](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/howtos/web_services.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Odoo to create your REST API by setting up controllers in your models.

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/backend/http.html

So you can either, not use Odoo for your rest api, or call odoo's REST API in your Django code!